# How can I make a bootable Windows 7 USB in OS X Lion?

Tags: macos, windows, startup

I want to make a bootable Windows 7 USB in OS X Lion. How can I do that?

Answer (score 4):

You need a install ISO image downloaded from Microsoft and a USB flash drive with 4GB or more.

#### Per the offical **[Bootcamp Guide for Lion](http://manuals.info.apple.com/en_US/boot_camp_install-setup_10.7.pdf#4)** by Apple (see page 4):

> You may be able to install Windows 7 with a USB flash drive that contains a Windows 7 **ISO image downloaded from Microsoft**. To check whether you can do so, open Boot Camp Assistant, click Continue, and see if the option “Create a Windows 7 install disk” is available. To install Windows 7 with a USB flash drive, you need the following:
>
> - An ISO image of Windows 7 Home Premium, Professional, or Ultimate downloaded from Microsoft.
> - **A USB flash drive with 4 GB or more**.
>     Boot Camp Assistant erases the flash drive, and copies to it the Windows 7 ISO
>     image and software drivers that let Windows work with your Mac hardware.
>
> To see how much free space you need on your disk for Windows, refer to the documentation that came with Windows.