# Create a Bootable Windows 7 USB from a Mac

Tags: bootcamp, usb, startup, windows

I found several old threads where similar situations were described with no practicable answer, so I ask again. Please forgive me if I am creating a redundant post but I have read the following threads with no answers:

[Using El Capitan, can I create a bootable Windows 7 USB?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/217631/using-el-capitan-can-i-create-a-bootable-windows-7-usb)

[Create a Bootable Windows USB from a OS X to work on a PC](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/123570/create-a-bootable-windows-usb-from-a-os-x-to-work-on-a-pc)

[Making a Bootable Windows 7 USB without Bootcamp](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/265618/making-a-bootable-windows-7-usb-without-bootcamp)

[How can I make a bootable Windows 7 usb in OSX Lion?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/52502/how-can-i-make-a-bootable-windows-7-usb-in-osx-lion)

[How can I create a Windows 7 usb from Mac OS to work on a PC?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/170079/how-can-i-create-a-windows-7-usb-from-mac-os-to-work-on-a-pc)

[Create a bootable usb from Yosemite.app](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/181139/create-a-bootable-usb-from-yosemite-app)

and so I create my own post.

I have a PC with a new Hard Drive. It lives in my tool box and I use it for servicing hardware that requires Windows 7. I have the .iso file on my MacBook Pro running Sierra. I have converted it to DMG, IMG and it's still also ISO.

I have used terminal to create a clone of the disk (disk utility fails with an error whenever I try to do anything with it, even after clean erase and install. I have a Mac running Mavericks coming out of storage I have yet to try with, and a Mac mini on Sierra which also has issues with Disk Utility doing anything without failing.

Anyway, the PC is a Dell Latitude 2100 with no optical drive, so I have to figure out how to make this bootable USB stick. So far when I clone the iso the PC sees it as a boot option, but says it's not bootable.

I know this isn't a Windows forum, so it may not be the best place, but my hope is that someone here knows a way to make a Windows bootable from my Mac.

I know BootCamp Assistant does this, but since I do have an Optical Drive, my Mac can not access that feature.

Please help, I have been spending a few hours a day on this for over a week now.

Comment: You said, "_I know BootCamp Assistant does this, but since I do have an Optical Drive, my Mac can not access that feature._", well my MBP doesn't have an optical drive yet Boot Camp Assistant gives me a choice to create a Windows 7 or later version install disk using the USB Flash Drive and an ISO Image.  What model Mac do you have an what version of OS X/macOS it it running?  Also have a look at: http://michael.anastasiou.me/create-windows-7-8-bootable-usb-drive-mac/

Comment: Boot Camp Assistant checks to see if the mac has an optical drive, and if it does have an optical drive, it can not make a USB. That feature is only for Macs that do not have an optical drive.

Comment: Tried that, the code sign command he gives does not appear to work on Sierra

Comment: It worked regardless, but will only allow Windows 10 or newer. I'm looking to make a Windows 7 disk. Any ideas?

Comment: Did you solve this?